# MongoDB on FreeBSD

Tags: mongodb, freebsd

We are currently using MongoDB 2.0.0 on MacOS but our servers are running FreeBSD. The most recent port of MongoDB is the 1.8.3 version. I have tried to compile the 2.0.0 by hand but I came across errors that I didn't manage to fix.

I came across on the Internet a few old resources which are saying that MongoDB does not run well on FreeBSD mainly for performance issue (`memory mapped files`). Is that true ? Does it mean we have to switch our server to another OS ?

Thanks for your opinions!

Sources :

- http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/8131b7e5a5c710d9
- http://ivoras.net/blog/tree/2009-11-05.a-short-time-with-mongodb.html

Comment: Without a reference it is hard to say (since it might be some special option, but in general freebsd supports memmapped files just fine, and like forever.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my original post. If it's true, It seems odd that MongoDB can be slower on FreeBSD than on Ubuntu/Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been reports in the past of issues with freebsd and mongo that related to memory mapped files.

I would recommend making a performance test based on your actual application.  Run it on MacOS and FreeBSD.  If FreeBSD is slower then something is wrong.  If your database will be larger than RAM be sure to test that case, that is probably the scenario where the virtual memory manager's behavior would be relevant.  MongoDB is relying on the operating system's virtual memory manager to manage the cache -- basically it's using the OS file system cache.